# How to pad a matrix to make it even sized in python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to take DCT of an image using opencv in python. However, for certain images I get the error

> The function/feature is not implemented (Odd-size DCT's are not implemented) in dct

This is because dct only supports even numbered arrays. In order to avoid this, how can I pad the matrix to make it even?

This is what I'm doing

```
img = cv2.imread(filepath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img = cv2.cvtColor(thresholded, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
gray = thresholded
gray = gray.astype('float32')
print gray.size
dct=cv2.dct(gray) #this gives error if gray.size is odd
```

The sample image I'm trying this on is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code I came up with for the very same problem. I think you should avoid using `resize`, especially when computing 'dct'. The resampling kernel (interpolation option) will have an impact on the image dct content. I therefore propose to use the `copyMakeBorder` function with default option set to `reflect101` which is, in my humble opinion, the most suited for frequency content analysis.

```
import cv2 as _cv2
import numpy as _np

def makeEvenSize(X, border=_cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101):
    """
    Copy image and extent data in order to get even size, if needed

    This function extends the array by a line in either
    down, right or both directions in order to get an even size.


    Args:
        X: np.ndarray arra
        border: border type to be used for extension (opencv convention)

    Example::

        # build a (5,5,3) shaped array
        X = np.dstack(3*(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5),))

        Y = makeEvenSize(X)

        print X[:,:,0]
        print Y[:,:,0]


        # In [211]: X[:,:,0]
        # array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        #        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        #        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        #        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        #        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
        #
        # In [212]: Y[:,:,0]
        # array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  3],
        #        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  8],
        #        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 13],
        #        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 18],
        #        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 23],
        #        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 18]], dtype=int32)


    """

    height, width = X.shape[0:2]

    top = 0
    bottom = (height % 2 == 1)
    left = 0
    right = (width % 2 == 1)

    Y = _cv2.copyMakeBorder(X, top, bottom, left, right, border)

    return Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure out which dimension (width/height) is odd and [resize()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)) it up a notch before submitting the image to `dct()`:

```
img = cv2.imread('foo.jpg')
height, width, channels = img.shape

if (height % 2 == 1)
    height += 1

if (width % 2 == 1)
    width += 1

resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think you can get the general idea.